URL Fragment Encoding - Dollar? [AWS]
What is the standard way to encode the fragment portion of a URL? (after the # symbol)
I noticed that on AWS CloudWatch for example, percent characters (%) in the fragment portion are encoded as '$25', so you'd see something like this:
.../home?region=us-west-1#logsV2:log-groups/log-group/$252Faws$252Flambda$252Ft...

The portion after /log-group/ should decode back to /aws/lambda/, which means some kind of double quoting, i.e.: / -> %2F ->. $252F
Is that some standard convention or is that specific to AWS? And if it is standard how does one accomplish this functionality with Python? (currently I have urllib.parse.quote(fragment, safe = '').replace('%', '$25') which seems a bit hacky).

P.S. - Is there a way to color some part of a code block here? (would make it clearer which portion I'm referring to in this query)

no, there's no user-controlled highlighting in code blocks. It has automatic syntax highlighting based on the language of the code block.

If there's any encoding required, it would be the same percent-encoding used in other parts of the URL. So I think this dollarsign stuff is specific to AWS.
